# Setting arrays in Firebase using Firebase console

Tags: arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I am using Firebase console for preparing data for a demo app. One of the data item is attendees. Attendees is an array. I want to add a few attendees as an array in Firebase. I understand Firebase does not have arrays, but object with keys (in chronological order). How do I do that for preparing sample data? My current Firebase data looks like the below.
[image]

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The Firebase Database doesn't store arrays. It stores dictionaries/associate arrays. So the closest you can get is:

```
attendees: {
  0: "Bill Gates",
  1: "Larry Page",
  2: "James Tamplin"
}
```

You can build this structure in the Firebase Console. And then when you read it with one of the Firebase SDKs, it will be translated into an array.

```
firebase.database().ref('attendees').once('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
  // ["Bill Gates", "Larry Page", "James Tamplin"]
});
```

So this may be the result that you're look for. But I recommend reading this blog post on why Firebase prefers it if you don't store arrays: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html.

## Don't use an array, when you actually need a set

Most developers are not actually trying to store an array and I think your case might be one of those. For example: can "Bill Gates" be an attendee twice?

```
attendees: {
  0: "Bill Gates",
  1: "Larry Page",
  2: "James Tamplin",
  3: "Bill Gates"
}
```

If not, you're going to have to check whether he's already in the array before you add him.

```
if (!attendees.contains("Bill Gates")) {
  attendees.push("Bill Gates");
}
```

This is a clear sign that your data structure is sub-optimal for the use-case. Having to check all existing children before adding a new one is going to limit scalability.

In this case, what you really want is a set: a data structure where each child can be present only once. In Firebase you model sets like this:

```
attendees: {
  "Bill Gates": true,
  "Larry Page": true,
  "James Tamplin": true
}
```

And now whenever you try to add Bill Gates a second time, it's a no-op:

```
attendees["Bill Gates"] = true;
```

So instead of having to code for the uniqueness requirement, the data structure implicitly solves it.

Comment: At the moment, pushing IDs in the console is not possible. I will either use a set or just do the push from the app. Thanks.

Comment: So can you use the Firebase console to populate the array or not!?

Answer (score 11):

To add arrays manually using Firebase Realtime DB console:

- Use double " " instead of single ' ' quotes

[image]

---

Which provides this structure:

[image]

Comment: I was using single quotes then I changed to double quotes and it worked!!

Answer (score 5):

After writing my other answer I realized that you might simply be looking how to add push IDs in the console.

That's not a feature at the moment. Most of is either use different types of keys when entering test data or have a little JavaScript snippet in another tab to generate the keys and copy/paste them over.

Please *do* request the feature [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/), since you're definitely not the first one to ask.

Answer (score 0):

firebase array ?yeah, i have same problem with you few weeks ago, but i found it in [here](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2017/05/convert-firebase-database-snapshotcollection-array-javascript/). Finally i can use it with my ChartJS.

```js
function jamToArray(snapshot) {
    const returnArr = [];
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        const item = childSnapshot.val().time;
        returnArr.push(item);
    });
    return returnArr;
};

firebase.database().ref('sensor').limitToLast(10).on('value', function(snapshot) {
    const jam       = jamToArray(snapshot);
});
```