# Firebase structuring and filtering multiple attributes (values) on key

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building a solution where I will need to add attributes such as color, type on my products. The products will be able to have more than one color.

So my question is, should I structure my data attributes as arrays in firebase, or objects, or is there an other way?

I would like to filter my products with .eQualTo (or if there is a better way)
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#equalTo

Example 1)

```
{
name: "My red n' white product",
color: ["white", "red"]
}
```

Example 2)

```
{
name: "My red n' white product",
color: {red: true, white: true}
},
{
name: "My blue product",
color: {blue : true}
}
```

Example 3) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to realized here:

- Whenever you feel the need to store an array, but then want to do a `contains()` operation on it: you are probably looking to store a set instead. See my previous answer here for more details: [Setting arrays in Firebase using Firebase console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40055764/setting-arrays-in-firebase-using-firebase-console/40055996#40055996)
- Even when you store the colors as a set, you will end up with queries like: `ref.orderByChild('color/blue').equalTo(true)`. While this query works, it requires that you have indexes defined for `['color/blue', 'color/red', 'color/white']`. As soon as your categories/colors are dynamic, this won't be possible since you can't programmatically add indexes.

The more idiomatic way to model this data is to "follow the use-case". You want to get a list of items for a specific category/color. So in that case, store a list of items for each color:

```
itemsByColor: {
  red: {
    keyOfRedAndWhiteProduct: true
  },
  white: {
    keyOfRedAndWhiteProduct: true
  },
  blue: {
    keyOfBlueProduct: true
  }
}
```

Now you can easily look up the list of item keys and then load them.

I highly recommend also reading the [Firebase guide on structuring data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data), specifically the section on [modeling data that scales](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#fanout). And this article on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) is mandatory reading for anyone making the transition to NoSQL database.