# How to push an object in array field using Firebase DB

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I want to push an object in array field of Firebase database.

I've tried,

```
  const friendObj = {
    first_name: item.first_name,
    last_name: item.last_name,
    username: item.username,
    phoneNumber: item.phoneNumber,
    email: item.email,
  }
  db.collection('users')
    .doc('documentId')
    .set({ friends: friendObj })
```

I want to add an object in `friends` array of below table.
My firebase table looks like below
[image]

Can anyone please help me, I'm having difficulty while add value in DB.

Comment: I've never used a firebase database, but could it be that your are not passing the email? making the query fail?

Comment: does'n matter @Auticcat

Comment: You can pass array data directly instead.

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data


`var docData = {
    stringExample: "Hello world!",
    booleanExample: true,
    numberExample: 3.14159265,
    dateExample: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date("December 10, 1815")),
    arrayExample: [5, true, "hello"],
    nullExample: null,
    objectExample: {
        a: 5,
        b: {
            nested: "foo"
        }
    }
};
db.collection("data").doc("one").set(docData).then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
});`

Comment: @Suniltc i've one object in array and i want to push other one!

Comment: This answer might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295541/cloud-firestore-update-fields-in-nested-objects-with-dynamic-key

Answer (score -1):

Firebase doesn't actually have a data type as arrays, but you have few alternatives to store data as an array using an alternative (like `sets`) and there are methods specifically to work with those.

Check this link for an implementation
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40055996/11945277

Comment: firebase has data type array @Asela

Comment: This isn't true. They do have arrays, and you can add things to them from the dashboard.

Comment: @HardikVirani  sorry to disappoint you guys, you can call it an array but technically its a different story as i mentioned. kindly follow the links i have shared and do some further reading on it too. here's something from the official blog : https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html